# Java class extends not working properly

Tags: java, class, extends

Am playing a bit around with java and am learning step by step. To not write my whole life story, here it comes.

I am making a text game with some stats, a player, enemies, etc. For this I am using classes. Lately, I came accross the "extends" function and am trying to implement it. I made a class character, which extends to player and enemy. When I execute the code it seems as it wouldn't inherit anything. Would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

P.S. which tags would be ok to use?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Character
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    int cc;
    int strength;
    int life;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Player extends Character
{
    int cc = rand.nextInt(20)+51;
    int strength = rand.nextInt(3)+4;
    int life = rand.nextInt(5)+16;
}

public class Enemy extends Character
{
    int cc = rand.nextInt(10)+31;
    int strength = rand.nextInt(3)+1;
    int life = rand.nextInt(5)+6;
}

class myClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)                                                       
    {
    Player argens = new Player();

    System.out.println("This is you:\n");
    System.out.println("Close Combat " + argens.getCC());
    System.out.println("Strength " + argens.getStrength());
    System.out.println("Life " + argens.getLife());


    Enemy kobold = new Enemy();

    fight (argens, kobold);

    fight (argens, kobold);
    }

    static void fight(Player p, Enemy e)
    {

        p.setLife(p.getLife() - e.getStrength());

System.out.println("\nRemaining life");

System.out.println(p.getLife());

System.out.println(e.getLife());

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you say it's not inheriting anything? If it wasn't, this wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Put the subclass code into a constrcutor, also you are re-declaring the variables `cc` `strength` etc not inheriting

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: Start with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html , it can help to understand what `extends` 'function' means.

Comment: "not working" => you just don"t use it properly

Comment: First of all, you should get familiar with the concepts of OOP. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Comment: I'd advise against naming the class `Character`, because there's already `java.lang.Character` which is guaranteed to give you confusing times and weird error messages.

Comment: Please dont blame me for my english.
I know, that it is not working in the corect way, otherwise I would not be asking here.

Thank you all for the help. You helped me to make another step into the world of java! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
public class Player extends Character
{
    int cc = rand.nextInt(20)+51;
    int strength = rand.nextInt(3)+4;
    int life = rand.nextInt(5)+16;
}
```

does not set fields of the superclass. It declares and sets new fields in the subclass, without touching fields of the superclass.

To set fields of the superclass, make the `protected` and set them in the constructor of the subclass:

```
public class Player extends Character
{
    public Player()
    {
        cc = rand.nextInt(20)+51;
        strength = rand.nextInt(3)+4;
        life = rand.nextInt(5)+16;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @AaronErdwyn Accept the answer then. :)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you are not overwriting these values in the base class but in the inherited.

You should initialize these values in a constructor.

Example:

```
public class Character {
  int cc;
  // ...
}

public class Player extends Character {
  public Player() {
    cc = 5;
    // ...
  }
}
```

What you did was declaring variables in the base class and not initializing them and declaring variables in the sub class with same name at the same time.

more reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Thanks for the help!